# flatten an RDD to get non repeating value pair in Spark using RDD

Tags: apache-spark

Consider the schema I have in the dataframe below in scala.

```
root
  |-- phonetic: string (nullable = true)
  |-- sigID: long (nullable = true)
```

I am basically grouping by phonetic.

```
featuers.rdd.groupBy(x => x.apply(0))
```

which will give me an rdd below

```
(abc,([1],[2],[3]))
(def,([9],[8]))
```

How do I flatten this to get a cartesian of (key,([value-a,value-b]))

```
abc,1,2
abc,1,3
abc,2,3
def,9,8
....
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in conjunction with `map` from the PySpark API. (Assuming you're using PySpark - this looks more like Scala to me...)

Comment: Yes i am using scala. Is there an equivalent in scala?

Comment: To be honest it is probably easier without doing the `groupBy`, and keeping it as a `DataFrame`

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan The `Seq` class (the base class for `List` and other sequences) in Scala is very powerful and includes a native [combinations](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.Seq). Map your values to a Seq and obtain your combinations.

Comment: what about if a `phonetic` has only one value?

Comment: BTW -- if you are really grouping by `phonetic` I believe it should be `x.apply(0)`

Comment: @DavidGriffin thanks , made the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just leave it as a `DataFrame` and do this:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...

df.as("df1").join(
  df.as("df2"),
  ($"df2.phonetic" === $"df1.phonetic") && ($"df1.sigID" !== $"df2.sigID")
).select($"df1.phonetic", $"df1.sigID", $"df2.sigID").show
```

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, to answer the original question, you can unwind the grouped data like this:

```
df.rdd.groupBy(x => x.apply(0)).flatMap(t => {
  val longs = t._2.toArray.map(r => r.getLong(1));
  longs.flatMap(l => longs.flatMap(l2 => {
    if (l != l2) Seq((t._1, l, l2));
    else Seq() 
  }))
}).collect

res35: Array[(Any, Long, Long)] = Array((def,9,8), (def,8,9), (abc,1,2), (abc,1,3), (abc,2,1), (abc,2,3), (abc,3,1), (abc,3,2))
```